Что не так с mysql в Openserver 6?
Работаю в VSCode, код на Python. Включил лог запросов к Mysql в OpenServer 6.0.0
Сам запрос к БД корректен. SELECT тоже работает. Но апдейта в БД не происходит. Если скопировать этот запрос из логов и вручную выполнить в Phpmyadmin - все срабатывает.
Перезагружать ПК, VSCode и Openserver пробовал, не помогает
Апдейчу в поле с типом TEXT, данные - json.dumps(dict)
С чем может быть связана данная проблема?
Запрос собирается и выполняется здесь. Думаю, может где-то в этом методе лишняя кавычка где-то ставится и Openserver в логах ее не выводит
def update(self, table:str, data: dict, where: str):
    """
    Обновить запись
    """
    _query = str()
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            _query += f"`{k}`='{v}'"
        elif isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
            _query += f"`{k}`='{json.dumps(v, ensure_ascii=False)}'"
        else:
            _query += f"`{k}`={str(v)}"
        _query += ','
    _query = _query[:-1]
    query = f"UPDATE {table} SET {_query} WHERE {where}"
    self.query(query)
    self._cursor.close()


В настройках подключения autocommit стоит? Если нет, то скорее всего commit надо делать в коде самостоятельно после выполнения запроса. В phpMyAdmin autocommit по умолчанию включен и данные фиксируются сразу без под. движений.

автокоммит не стоит, но self._connection.commit() прописан в self.query(query)

В таком случае мне пока не очень понятно, в чём может быть проблема. В таких случаях лучше локализовать проблему до более конкретной. Попробуйте вставить простейший фиксированный update к какой-нибудь таблице - если он пройдет, проблема в запросе, если нет, то в коде обращения к БД. Отсюда тогда можно будет либо запрос сам смотреть более детально, либо код обращения к бд, сделав его тоже минимальным с открытием/закрытием ресурсов connection/cursor. Ну или подождать еще ответов, может кто-то тут увидит проблему сразу.

Попробовал сделать апдейт для другого поля TEXT, но в которое загружается не json.dumps(dict), а короткая строка. Работает... Но блин, если dict преобразуется в строку, только длинную, откуда могут взяться проблемы... Напомню, что в логах запрос корректный фиксируется

Тогда для последней проверки, я бы взял этот запрос из логов и прямо его вставил на выполнение методом. Отработает - значит можно поискать уже символы, которые мешают запросу, но режутся логированием. Но если не отработает, то выяснять причины поведения будет сложнее, но хотя бы с этим уже можно конкретнее работать и причина в тексте запроса. В любом случае уже куда-то сдвинулись с точки)

ошибка была в собственной непредусмотрительности. проверка на SELECT запрос была такой
if query.upper().find('SELECT') == -1:
            self._connection.commit()

вместо
if not query.upper().startswith('SELECT'):
            self._connection.commit()

а в query была переменная с названием select, от того коммит и не делался... Спасибо
